# Do links need to be provided for images included in a poster?

Tags: conference, poster, hyperlinks

I'm a PhD student making a poster for a conference. I'd like to include a figure with two images taken by a NASA satellite. Do I need to provide links to the images in the caption, or would it be enough to just give credit for the images in the way that NASA recommends? Below is the current version of the figure; the links are long and make the caption look awkward.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think a link is required? Are you providing links to all your references?

Comment: @user2705196 I'm not including links for the papers that I cite. I'm including links for the images because my adviser suggested that I do that.

Comment: If your advisor makes a suggestion that you disagree with it's a good idea to discuss their motivation behind the suggestion and explain why you disagree! They may have very specific reasons that we're not privy to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the images is essential. Beyond that, unless the conference has special requirements, nothing is really needed. Give enough of a citation that someone can chase down a link if they really need it. But such links in printed proceedings are unlikely to be followed by more than a small handful of folks.

If the proceedings are online, however, it can be useful to give the link, but not essential. Only proper citation is needed.